# Mobile width view not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, meta

For some reason I cannot display in mobile version my div as 100% width. Here is my JSX code:

```html
    <div>
          <div expand="lg" className="login-header">
            <h1>logo</h1>
            <h1>Welcome to Wealth Analytica</h1>
            <h1>Back to site</h1>
          </div>
              /******HERE IS SOME OTHER CODE THAT IS NOT RELATED*******/
    </div>
```

And my css is:

```css
      .login-header {
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #343a40;
      width:100%;
    }
```

Mobile view is not as expected:

[image]

The ordinary view is OK. My meta tag is:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Can someone give advice? I tried several different things but without success.

Comment: Why do you use className not class?

Comment: Because this is in React project

Comment: Okay, I tried your css and for me it works well. Maybe you can show some more code around that div?

Answer (score 0):

Div's will only be as wide as the container they are in. Because the surrounding div does not have a width specified the width of 100% on login-header has no affect. Try setting the width on the parent div to 1200px and see if that changes the behavior. All that being said I would highly recommend a css framework like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) as it takes care of that stuff for you. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried adding to parent div bootstrap className="container-fluid" but still not working on mobile version. Usually I am using bootstrap classes but in this case something is wrong. I updated with the whole code.

Comment: Thats the correct answer. Not sure what's the width of container-fluid, but if that has not been set, width: 100% won't work as you expected

Comment: even if you manually set it to 100% nothing has changed. Also if this was the problem it should be OK if I am displaying it in normal view either - but it is OK.